# PyQt4, can't open Designer

Tags: lubuntu, pyqt

When i try to open from the console using "designer" it says:

```
designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer': No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to fix it. Help please

I'm using Lubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

That file is [provided by](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=qt4%2Fbin%2Fdesigner&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) the `qt4-designer` package. Try installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-designer
```